# Way to extend Marionette.js view classes

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I need to extend marionette.js classes with some functionality I'd like to have in all classes I create in my app.

What I currently do is to save original method of Marionette and to override it with my own method, calling to original from inside overridden.

For instance:

```
(function() {
  var oldMarionetteItemViewConstructor = Marionette.ItemView.prototype.constructor;
  Marionette.ItemView.prototype.constructor = function() {
     // Some custom stuff I want to have here
     .....
     // Call to original constructor
     return oldMarionetteItemViewConstructor.call(this, arguments);
  }
})();
```

It seems some hacky and I wonder if there better way?

Answer (score 3):

Marionette hoists the Backbone.View.extend() method (which itself is actually hoisted from Underscore.js) so all you have to do is:

```
var MyFancyView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({

    //define your custom stuff here

});

var MyExtendedView = MyFancyView.extend({

    //This view picks up the same props/methods form MyFancyView

});
```

You're pattern works, but the native `#extend()` method will keep your prototypes clean:
https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js#L838